# Не получается считать файл с помощью ifstream на c++

Tags: c++, ifstream

Нужно посимвольно прочесть файл, но почему-то ifstream не видит файл, пытался указать полный адрес файла, даже так выводит файл не открыт.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;




int main() {
    char element;
    setlocale(0, "rus");
    ifstream myfile("name.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (myfile.get(element))
        {
            cout << element;
        }
        myfile.close();
    }

    else cout << "Файл не открыт";

}`введите сюда код`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно вы неправильно указали относительные/абсолютные пути. Ваш код является рабочим. У меня успешно запускаются (с выводом содержимого файла на консоль) следующие варианты:

1. Абсолютный путь (Windows-стиль)

```
ifstream myFile("C:\\Users\\oQaris\\Desktop\\name.txt");
```

2. Абсолютный путь (Linux-стиль)

```
ifstream myFile("C:/Users/oQaris/Desktop/name.txt");
```

3. Относительный путь (файл должен лежать в том же каталоге, что скомпилированная программа, в моём случае - это *cmake-build-debug*)

```
ifstream myFile("name.txt");
```

Comment: я попробовал даже файл вставить в корневую папку в диск C "C:\name.txt" и исправил на ifstream myfile("C:\name.txt");  , и даже так он не работает.

Comment: Обратные слэши надо экранировать, либо писать прямые слэши в пути. Попробуйте `ifstream myfile("C:/name.txt");`

Comment: даже с такими слэшами не работает.  В консоле выводит файл не открыт. Можете проблема в программе VS?

Comment: я понял в чем была проблема. Я сохранил файл в другую папку, но кнопка "локальный отладчик Windows" был привязан к другому файлу. Теперь у меня проблема с кодировкой. В cmd установлен кодировка 866 и он не способен выводит русские символы

Comment: @mArSeN, уже пробовали `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF-8');`?

Comment: не работает, проблема в кодировке, а вашу запись он игнорирует. Пришлось кодировку файла менять на ANSI